# CSS filter() Transformation/transition time

Tags: css, css-transitions, css-filters

I've got a CSS filter for blurring an element and it works beautifully... But I'd like it to ease into the blur but can't figure out what css `transition-property` controls it?

I was using `transition: 1s;` but that breaks another animation on the element (it slides out to the left).

```
.event {
     // transition: 1s; // Works with blur() but breaks other animations
}

.event:hover {
     -moz-filter: blur(5px);
     -ms-filter: blur(5px);
     -o-filter: blur(5px);
     -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
     filter: blur(5px);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *property name* in a declaration is always the portion before the colon, even if the *value* is a function. So, the corresponding `transition-property` is `filter`:

```
.event {
    transition-property: -moz-filter, -ms-filter, -o-filter, -webkit-filter, filter;
    transition-duration: 1s;
}
```

This applies not just to the `filter` property, but also to properties like `transform` and such that typically accept functions as values.

This also means that if you have, for example, multiple different filters or multiple transforms, all of them for a given property will be animated.

Comment: @Wallter: I accepted your edit but I'm not sure if browsers will correctly apply their relevant prefixes and safely ignore the others. I've seen [Chrome completely break down on other unrecognized transition properties](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22457222/ie10-11-uses-transform-webkit-transform/22457802#22457802) for example. It might be worth specifying each transition property separately instead.

Comment: I'm about to roll this out to Dev QA and regression testing, I'll report back if anything breaks. Although, I do develop primarily with Chrome (Stable, Beta, and Canary) and didn't have a problem - the arguments are in the same order... but we'll see