# Hover Effect Looks Buggy ( Microsoft Edge )

Tags: html, css, animation, hover

I have a Problem, in Edge this Hover Effect Looks realy bad :(

**Microsoft Edge:**
[Link Hover GIF (imgur)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J5EwI.gif)

**Google Chrome:**

[Link Hover GIF ( imgur )](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wunE8.gif)

In Google Chrome it looks fine, but as soon as I try Microsoft Edge it looks very shitty. Is there a way to fix it?

Code:

**HTML**

```
<div class="event--event__mod">
<a class="event--event__mod__item" href="censored">
<div class="event--mod__title">Problem Title</div>
 <div class="event--mod__date">Date</div>              
 <div class="event--mod__price">105,00&€</div></a></div
```

**CSS**

```
.mod-ohanah--events {
  margin-left: -30px;
}
.mod-ohanah--events:after {
  content: '';
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
  clear: both;
  display: block;
}
.mod-ohanah--events .event--event__mod {
  float: left;
  padding-left: 30px;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin-bottom: 35px;
}
@media screen and (min-width:640px){
  .mod-ohanah--events .event--event__mod {
    width: 50%;
  }
}
@media screen and (min-width:1000px){
  .mod-ohanah--events .event--event__mod {
    width: 33.333333333%;
  }
}
.uk-panel-space .mod-ohanah--events .event--event__mod {
  width: 100%;
}

.mod-ohanah--events .event--event__mod__item {
  background: #FFF;
  display: block;
  color: #000;
  padding: 40px 35px 30px;
  height: 260px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
}
.uk-panel-space .mod-ohanah--events .event--event__mod__item {
  height: 260px;
}
.mod-ohanah--events .event--event__mod__item:focus {
  outline: none;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.mod-ohanah--events .event--event__mod__item:hover {
  background: #f14a70;
  color: #FFF;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.mod-ohanah--events .event--event__mod__item .event--mod__title {
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #000;
  font-weight: 200;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  transition: all 0.667s cubic-bezier(0.16, 1, 0.29, 0.99);
}
@media screen and (min-width: 768px){
  .mod-ohanah--events .event--event__mod__item .event--mod__title {
    font-size: 16px;
  }
}
@media screen and (min-width:1000px){
  .mod-ohanah--events .event--event__mod__item .event--mod__title {
    font-size: 20px;
  }
}
@media screen and (min-width:1220px){
  .mod-ohanah--events .event--event__mod__item .event--mod__title {
    font-size: 24px;
  }
}

.uk-panel-space .mod-ohanah--events .event--event__mod__item .event--mod__title {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
.mod-ohanah--events .event--event__mod__item:hover .event--mod__title {
  color: #FFF;
}

.mod-ohanah--events .event--event__mod__item .event--mod__date {
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.mod-ohanah--events .event--mod__price {
  line-height: 38px;
  padding: 0 18px;
  background: #f4f4f4;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #797979;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 30px;
  left: 35px;
  transition: all 0.667s cubic-bezier(0.16, 1, 0.29, 0.99) !important;
}
.mod-ohanah--events .event--event__mod__item:hover .event--mod__price {
  background: transparent;
  border: 1px solid #FFF;
  color: #FFF;
}
```

Comment: Found this similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42242690/ms-edge-css-transition-flickering and it's answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42570861/3909588

Comment: @MaxSeelig Already saw that but isnt the Problem of the Post you sent that `transition-property: all` is causing the Bug? I dont use it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Problem got fixed with the new Fall Creators Update.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try adding

```
transition: background 0.667s cubic-bezier(0.16, 1, 0.29, 0.99), color 0.667s cubic-bezier(0.16, 1, 0.29, 0.99);
```

Refer to each property that needs to be transitioned

In stead of

```
transition: all 0.667s cubic-bezier(0.16, 1, 0.29, 0.99);
```

Comment: Good Idea but not fixing the problem :(

Comment: Could you make me a jsfiddle?

Comment: Cant get the jsfiddle to get working... Can I sent you the URL via twitter? Because i dont want the Website getting Indexed by Google on Stackoverflow :D